# How do I return a new length of the array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function called push which accepts two parameters, an array and any value.

The function should add the value to the end of the array and then return the new length of the array.

Do not use the built in `Array.push() function!`

Examples:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
push(arr, 10); // 4

arr; // [1, 2, 3, 10]
```

My question is `How to return a new array with the new length`.

Comment: There's many ways to make a new array out of several other ones. Search MDN.

Comment: Searching MDN for all the functions regarding arrays should give you some clues, as well as look into array slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out . Get the length of the existing array and put the new number at arr[length] index of it . See the code below:

```
    function push(arr,num){
        var length = arr.length;
        arr[length]=num;
        return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with something like this:

```js
const push = (a, v) => (a[a.length] = v,a);
array = [1,2,3]
console.log(push(array, 4));
```